# How to increase UICollectionView height dynamically as it's content size increases?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` and inside that `UICollectionView` there are three cells and one header.
The header is for image.
And the three cells are for Social likes,About and Gallery.
Here is the view[image]

Inside that Gallery cell there is a `UICollectionView` .
I want that `UICollectionView` (Inside Gallery Cell) increases it's height as it's content increases so that the Gallery Cell increases it's height then the whole the View i.e the parent `UICollectionView` will increase it's height and the whole page will scroll.

I can't increase the height of the `UICollectionView` inside the Gallery Cell dynamically as it's content increases so that the Gallery Cell will increase it's height dynamically and the whole page will increase it's height dynamically.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a constraint of the collection view height and set it to collection view content size.

Comment: But I am getting collection view content size zero. Inside layoutsubviews method

Comment: what do you mean content size is zero?   In this method?  `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout!, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) ` 
?